# Why am I getting undefined while accessing an array inside an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object

`let newdata = await tripModel.find(`
`{ tripId: ID },`
`{salesOrder:1, no: "$deliveryDetails.invoiceNo", _id: 0 }`
`);`

```
let nullInvoices = [];

console.log("vvvvvvv", newdata[0].salesOrder);
for (let i = 0; i < newdata[0].no.length; i++) {
  if (newdata[0].no[i] === null)
    nullInvoices.push({
      SO: newdata[0].salesOrder[i],
      invoice: newdata[0].no[i],
    });
}`
```

> //error: vvvvvvv {
> salesOrder: [
> 623d917d4c9f21730ace6256,
> 623da8bbeae48b2f34372a95,
> 623da8bbeae48b2f34372a92,
> 623d98964c9f21730ace642c
> ],
> no: [ null, '0900009293', '0900009294', null ]
> }
> reason TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
>
> I need to access "no", but it is throwing as undefined.

Comment: I think you need this : `newdata[0].salesOrder.no.length`

Answer (score 1):

Since your

`console.log("vvvvvvv", newdata[0].salesOrder);` statement returns

```
{
    salesOrder: [ 623d917d4c9f21730ace6256, 623da8bbeae48b2f34372a95, 623da8bbeae48b2f34372a92, 623d98964c9f21730ace642c ],
    no: [ null, '0900009293', '0900009294', null ],
}
```

your iteration must be like as below

```
let nullInvoices = [];

console.log("vvvvvvv", newdata[0].salesOrder);
for (let i = 0; i < newdata[0].salesOrder.no.length; i++) {
  if (newdata[0].salesOrder.no[i] === null)
    nullInvoices.push({
      SO: newdata[0].salesOrder.salesOrder[i],
      invoice: newdata[0].salesOrder.no[i],
    });
}
```

**Sample Implementation**

```js
const newdata = [{}];

newdata[0].salesOrder = {
  salesOrder: ['623d917d4c9f21730ace6256', '623da8bbeae48b2f34372a95', '623da8bbeae48b2f34372a92', '623d98964c9f21730ace642c'],
  no: [null, '0900009293', '0900009294', null],
}

let nullInvoices = [];

for (let i = 0; i < newdata[0].salesOrder.no.length; i++) {
  if (newdata[0].salesOrder.no[i] === null)
    nullInvoices.push({
      SO: newdata[0].salesOrder.salesOrder[i],
      invoice: newdata[0].salesOrder.no[i],
    });
}

console.log(nullInvoices);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can make an `invoices` object first, and then filter it by any condition:

```js
const data = {salesOrder: [ '623d917d4c9f21730ace6256', '623da8bbeae48b2f34372a95', '623da8bbeae48b2f34372a92', '623d98964c9f21730ace642c'],no: [ null, '0900009293', '0900009294', null ]};

const invoices = data.salesOrder
  .map((SO, index) => ({ SO, invoice: data.no[index] }));

const nullInvoices = invoices
  .filter(({ invoice }) => invoice === null);
  
console.log(nullInvoices);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```